# How to schedule a lambda function to run 2 hours after another lambda function logs a specific entry?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to run a lambda function 2 hours after another lambda function logs an entry like so `console.log ('ScheduleSecondFunction');`

Is there a way to do that using CloudWatch?

Answer (score 2):

I think steps to your goal could involve CloudWatch (CW) custom  [metric filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringPolicyExamples.html) to detect `ScheduleSecondFunction` entry in your CW Logs. The metric would be used to define a **CW Alarm**. When the alarm triggers it send a **SNS notification** to a **lambda function**. The function would parse the alarm event and and start a **Step Function** with [Wait](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) state. The state would **wait 2 hours** and then invoke your final lambda function.

There are some alternatives to the above. Instead of using SNS and the second, intermediate lambda function, you could use **CW Events rule** to [detect alarm change](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-cloudwatch-sends-alarm-state-change-events-amazon-eventbridge/) and trigger Step Function directly from the CW Events. This could reduce the complexity of using SNS and intermediate lambda function.

Yet another possibility, could be setting up the CW Alarm with a period of 2 hours. However, I'm not sure how using **2 hour period** in CW Alarm would behave in your scenario. But if this would work, then you could eliminate the Step Function, as you could trigger your final lambda function directly from the CW Alarms. But its something that could be tested and verified.